# How can i Changes in the last property of the ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf

How can i Changes in the last property of the `ControlTemplate`?
in the following code i want to change the last Expander property to True. I mean the the first and the second and the third and .... Expander property is being false and the last one is being True.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="1">
```

my code like this:

```
<ScrollViewer  
   x:Name="scrollviewer" 
   Height="300" 
   Width="270"  
   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   CanContentScroll="True" >
   <ItemsControl x:Name="lstComment" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=count}" />
               <TextBlock Text=" " />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=comment}" />
               <TextBlock Text=" " />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RedSentence}" Foreground="Red"/>
               <TextBlock Text=" " />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BlueSentence}" Foreground="Blue"/>
               <TextBlock Text=" " />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5" />
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                     <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                           <Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="1">
                              <Expander.Header>
                                 <DockPanel Background="Yellow">
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="200" />
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" />
                                 </DockPanel>
                              </Expander.Header>
                              <Expander.Content>
                                 <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                 </Border>
                              </Expander.Content>
                           </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                     </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
               </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
         </GroupStyle>
      </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new boolean property to GroupItem class. This property will indicate whether Expander for this GroupItem is expanded or not. Then you can bind Expander IsExpanded property to GroupItem property.

Comment: Thanks.can you give me a example ?